# What would be the another possible answer?

Tags: contest-math

It is easy to guess that 51 is the missing number. The entries in the last row are obtained by taking multiplication of entries in third and second row and subtracting entries in first row in the same column. Is another idea possible to get another answer? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you view the middle column as the median of the other two, the last entry can be $49$.

Remark: Such questions are not properly phrased and it is hard to justify what is the answer.

Comment: Can one say that this is an example of an ill-posed problem?

Comment: hmm... i might need a definition of ill-posed problem to answer that. the question is too open ended.